# Cannot Run TomCat server on Ecliples getting the error that failed to start

Tags: tomcat

I am Getting `Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start` while I am running Tomcat server at localhost. I have gone through many Stack-overflow pages but my problem have not solved

[image]

Comment: The port is already used by another program.

Answer (score 0):

I Have Solved The Issue : The Issue is because of the Host File Located At
For Windows

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

In that path the Host File is changed, Check weather your host File is proper with Proper Configuration